# TeX Live Manager log

Tags: texlive

Where does TeX Live store its logs of recent updates or installations of packages? I want to see what packages were installed recently. I have looked at the installation folder but have not found such a log file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For Unix-like systems, TeX Live Manager stores its logs in `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/web2c`, file `tlmgr.log`.

Answer (score 7):

For Windows systems, it appears to be stored in `texmf-var\web2c` within your TeX Live installation root.

Thus, if your TeX Live is installed in, say,

`D:\Programs\TeX.Live`,

then the log is at

`D:\Programs\TeX.Live\texmf-var\web2c\tlmgr.log`